# How to implement an "Excel like" "add cell" into a canvas

Tags: image-processing, draw, image-manipulation

I'm sorry for the title, that maybe can't describe properly what I would like to achieve. I'm starting to develop a new software which should present a "grid" to the user that can be manipulated by him adding "rows" or "columns" in any point of this "grid". The problem is that I'm not sure a real grid is the suitable solution, because there are some "graphical" requirements like changing invididual cells sizes, nesting them, zooming/stretching, etc. So I was starting to analyze a solution in WPF that uses DrawingVisual elements (for performance reason).
I'm able to draw the "grid" in the desired way. I'm also able to add rows or columns at the edges of the drawing. But I can't figure any solution to modify it in the "middle" (except redrawing the whole thing). I'll explain me better with an image. On the left there's the "grid" after it has been drawn for the first time. On the right there's a new grid that should be drawn after the user performs an operation.

[image]

An more complex example is the following, where the "row" is added inside an existing cell, causing all the cells to "grow".

[image]

As I said, I know I could redraw the whole thing, but I'm concerned about performance. Keep in mind that in a real scenario there could be thousands of blocks and many nesting levels.

Any suggestion is appreciated. The use of WPF is not mandatory, but it will be a desktop app in .NET 5.0. The use of a DrawingVisual is neither mandatory. I can evaluate any solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple technique is to keep positions of columns relative to the left of the canvas in a variable when you first draw the tables. When you want to add a new column, you can crop the image from that point, and in a larger canvas, copy the left and right pieces and just draw the middle column from the beginning.

Of course, the coordinates of each column can be calculated with image processing techniques, but it reduces performance.

I wrote this code with Python, but I do not think it would be difficult to convert it to C#.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# copy image over another
def imdraw(im, over, x, y):
    y1, y2 = y, y + over.shape[0]
    x1, x2 = x, x + over.shape[1]
    for c in range(0, 3):
        im[y1:y2, x1:x2, c] = over[:, :, c]
    return im


pt = 220
col = 300
off = 15

im = cv2.imread("grid.png", 1)
h, w = im.shape[:2]

crop_left = im[0 : 0 + h, 0:pt]
crop_right = im[0 : 0 + h, pt:w]

cv2.imwrite("left.jpg", crop_left)
cv2.imwrite("right.jpg", crop_right)

# Create an Empty image with white background
out = 255 * np.ones(shape=[h, w + col, 3], dtype=np.uint8)

out = imdraw(out, crop_left, 0, 0)
out = imdraw(out, crop_right, pt + col, 0)

out = cv2.rectangle(
    out,
    pt1=(pt + off, off),
    pt2=(pt + col - off, h - off),
    color=(128, 0, 200),
    thickness=5,
    lineType=cv2.LINE_AA,
)

cv2.imwrite("out.jpg", out)
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's a good suggestion and I already tried something similar. My second example is a bit more complex because I cannot just crop/clip the image! Anyway, I'll try to elaborate your idea in the next days!

Comment: @ufo Please :) I came up with a few different ideas for the second case. If the size of the canvas is changed, the problem will be solved. But if the cells need to be shrinked, I think if only the border cells are redrawn, the problem will be solved. I am involved in a project, if the time comes I will write an example of the second case :)