# Insert edited image patch back into original image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I am fairly new to Python, so excuse any blindingly obvious oversights.

I have indexed part of an image, performed some processing on the indexed patch (not shown), and now need to reinsert the processed patch back into the original image. Ideally, the transition between original image and processed patch would be smooth and not introduce artifacts.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import numpy
import rasterio as rio
import imageio

# read image to be processed
img = rio.open('path/to/image')
img = img.read(1) # convert to array for processing

# define image patch to be processed (original image size: 19,968px x 19,968px)
ind = 1536 # first index position
L = 16898 # length of image
img = img[ind:ind+L,ind:ind+L]

## PROCESSING OF PATCH DONE HERE ##

# convert to uint8 to match original image
img_done = img_done.astype(np.uint8)

# what I tried so far
img_done[ind:ind+L,ind:ind+L] = img
```

The final line gives the broadcast error `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (16898,16898) into shape (15362,15362)`

How do I go about inserting the processed patch correctly?

Comment: Hello @stanbybee :) welcome to stackoverflow; It seems you want to put the bigger image inside the smaller one (ValueError) - I'm not sure what do you want to reach at the end; but maybe this link can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/67455241/2227070

Comment: Hi @Shamshirsaz.Navid, I experimented with your approach, but it didn't help me in this case. Could I insert the image more simply with numpy/python indexing? I am trying to work out where the (15362,15362) shape comes from as the original image is (19968,19968) and the edited patch (16898,16898)...